# using splat operator to pass optional parameters does not work as expected

Tags: python

I have a generic function that accept 2 parameters (int) as A and B as required ones, and 2 more as optional; this is the function signatute

```
myfunct(a, b, c=False, d="joe")
```

a and b are int, c is a bool and d is str type.

I am using the `splat` operator to pass a list, so based on how many parameter I get from `argparse` I can add the optional parameters or not. Sometimes I get the call to the function as

```
myfunct 21, 32
```

Sometimes as

```
myfunct 34, 44, c=True
```

And all the other variants in between

although I did notice that the splat function does not pass the optional parameter correctly. instead it pass the parameters in sequence, even if I specify which optional parameter I am using.

```
thelist = [21, 32, "d="+"mike"]

myfunct(*thelist]
```

When I look at what I get in each variable in my function, I get correctly both `a` and `b`, but instead of getting `mike` in the `d` optional parameter, I get it in `c`, and it assign the whole string, instead of just what is after the `=` sign

so this is the content of the variables:

```
a -> 21
b -> 32
c -> d=mike
```

While I was expecting

```
a -> 21
b -> 32
d -> mike
```

how does one pass optional arguments using splat operator? Or is this a bad idea to start with?

Comment: use `**` and a dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a list can be unpacked for positional arguments, which you've obviously figured out, for keyword arguments, you need a dictionary.

```
args = [21, 32]
kwargs = {"c": "mike"}

def test_function(a, b, c=None):
    print(a, b, c)

test_function(*args, **kwargs)
# (21, 32, 'mike')
```

This isn't inherently a bad idea, but when you do something like this, make sure you're keeping in mind how it could impact readability for someone looking at your code (including yourself in a couple months after this is no longer fresh in your mind).

Comment: Awesome, I was not aware of the 2 stars and that dictionary would work in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Give the keyword arguments (kwargs) via a dict, expanded with `**`:

```
args = [21, 32]
kwargs = {"d": "mike"}
myfunct(*args, **kwargs)
```